# Remove multiple rows based on condition in multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have dataset like this from csv file.[image]

I want to remove all records that has question mark ('?') in any of their column. I tried this code:

```
for column in df.columns:
    df = df[df[column] != '?']
```

But it does not work, here is the output.[image]
My expected output is index **1** and **3** get removed. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter all rows without `?` with space:

```
out = df[(df != ' ?').all(axis=1)]
```

Or if possible use `read_csv` and no missing values, only `?` use:

```
 out = pd.read_csv(file, na_values=' ?').dropna()
```

Comment: i tried both and both do not work

Comment: @wiryadev - e.g. for row 1 what is `print (df.loc[1].tolist())` ?

Comment: thanks for replying that, turns out it is the value is ' ?', there is space in that. Thanks for helping me